# PHP & RSS Feeds & Special Characters validation Problem

Tags: php, rss

I keep getting the following validation warning below. And I was wondering that some of my articles deal with special characters and was wondering how should I go about rendering or not rendering special characters in my RSS feeds? Should I use htmlentites or not? If so how?

> In addition, interoperability with the
>   widest range of feed readers could be
>   improved by implementing the following
>   recommendations. line 22, column 35:
>   title should not contain HTML: `&amp;`

PHP code.

```
<title>' . htmlentities(strip_tags($title), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</title>
```

Comment: feedvalidator.org (Feedburner recommends this site to validate your feeds) says: "For the widest interop, the RSS Profile recommends the use of the hexadecimal character reference "&#x26;" to represent "&" and "&#x3C;" to represent "<".  It's 2013 and I can't find a PHP function to give me a valid RSS title? LOL.

Answer (score 3):

You should use CDATA To escape characters in your XML feeds, this allows you to use your raw data without disrupting the XML layout.

Try this:

```
<title><![CDATA[ YOUR RAW CONTENT]]></title>
```

Note: do not use htmlentites and strip_tags as this will escape them for the browser, and any other reader should read them correctly.

Qoute from w3schools:

> The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.
>   Characters like `"<"` and `"&"` are illegal in XML elements.
>   `"<"` will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.
>   `"&"` will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.
>   Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of `"<"` or `"&"` characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.
>   Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.
>   A CDATA section starts with "":

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: can I keep the strip_tags function when using CDATA?

Comment: the CDATA display only `$title` not the best idea?

Comment: you may have to echo it out, `$title` is a variable so you should have `<![CDATA[<?php echo $title ?>]]>` to output the content.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code as im sure you have missed something, my answer should be working.

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org (Feedburner recommends this site to validate your feeds) complains if you use CDATA in your titles.  Not sure if this is a recent change or not, but I discovered the problem this morning.

Answer (score 1):

/* feedvalidator.org (Feedburner recommends this site to validate your feeds) says: "For the widest interop, the RSS Profile recommends the use of the hexadecimal character reference "&" to represent "&" and "<" to represent "<". */

```
        // find title problems
        $find[] = '<';
        $find[] = '\x92';
        $find[] = '\x84';

        // find content problems
        $find_c[] = '\x92';
        $find_c[] = '\x84';
        $find_c[] = '&nbsp;';

        // replace title
        $replace[] = '&#x3C;';
        $replace[] = '&#39;';
        $replace[] = '&#34;';

        // replace content
        $replace_c[] = '&#39;';
        $replace_c[] = '&#34;';
        $replace_c[] = ' ';

        // We don't want to re-replace "&" characters.  
        // So do this first because of PHP "feature" https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33773
        $title = str_replace('&', '&#x26;', $title); 
        $title = str_replace($find, $replace, $title);
        $post_content = str_replace($find_c, $replace_c, $row[3]);

        // http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/merchant-center/nIVyFrJsjpk
        $link = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $link);
```

Of course I'm doing some pre-processing before $title, $post_content and $link are added to my database.  But this should help solve some common problems to get a valid RSS feed.

Update: Fixed the &#x26;#x26;#x26; "recursion" problem, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33773

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `htmlentities()`. It's only for HTML files.

Comment: if you display titles from your xml file on an html page at some point, then you would want to use htmlentities() before printing to the page, but not when generating the xml file.